# Convert InputStreamResource to a POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, inputstream, pojo

My use case is to read a csv file and convert it to an already existing POJO. To read the file we have a library which returns InputStreamResource. I do not know how to go from InputStreamResource to a POJO.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to map CSV to POJO using streams is this.

```
List<Person> persons = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamResource.getInputStream()))
                        .lines()
                        .map(line -> mapToPerson(line.split(",")))
                        .skip(1) //skip first line for csv headers
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());


Person mapToPerson(String[] line) {
    return new Person(line[0], line[1]);
}

class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful :)